# RecyclerView not showing anything, although there not seem to be any problems

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am a bit comfused at this moment. In order to save time I used Android Studio's template for Navigation Drawer Activity. I was planning to create a Navigation Drawer and pass it through the rest of the activities. The first Activity did go well. The problem is with the second one, as I want to have the Navigation Drawer and create a RecyclerView.
So my code is:

Content_main2.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.sparrowred.sendcard.Main2Activity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main2">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/imageRecycleView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

app_bar_main2.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.sparrowred.sendcard.Main2Activity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main2" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

nav_header_main2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
    android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:src="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:text="Android Studio"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="android.studio@android.com" />

</LinearLayout>
```

activity_main2.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

image_list_row:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/image_descrprtion"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/imageId"
        android:src="@drawable/profile"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="dummy"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

imageAdapter.java:

```
package com.sparrowred.sendcard;

public class imageAdapter {
    private String title;
    private int imageId;

    public imageAdapter() {
    }

    public imageAdapter(String title, int imageId) {
        this.title = title;
        this.imageId = imageId;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title){
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getTitle(){
        return this.title;
    }

    public void setImageId(int imageId){
        this.imageId = imageId;
    }

    public int getImageId(){
        return this.imageId;
    }
}
```

imageDescriptionArray.java (I need to change the name :P):

```
package com.sparrowred.sendcard;

import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

public class imageDescriptionArray extends RecyclerView.Adapter<imageDescriptionArray.MyViewHolder> {

    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private List<imageAdapter> imageAdapterList;

    public imageDescriptionArray(List<imageAdapter> imageAdapterList) {
        this.imageAdapterList = imageAdapterList;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.image_list_row, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        imageAdapter iva = imageAdapterList.get(position);
        holder.title.setText(iva.getTitle());
        holder.image.setImageResource(iva.getImageId()); 
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return imageAdapterList.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView title;
        public ImageView image;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
            image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageId);
        }
    }

}
```

and finally Main2Activity.java:

```
package com.sparrowred.sendcard;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import jp.wasabeef.recyclerview.animators.SlideInUpAnimator;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {


    private RecyclerView mImageRecycleView;
    private List<imageAdapter> imageAdapterList;
    private imageDescriptionArray mAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        mImageRecycleView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.imageRecycleView);
        mImageRecycleView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        imageAdapterList = new ArrayList<>(12);
        mAdapter = new imageDescriptionArray(imageAdapterList);
        LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new  LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        mImageRecycleView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mImageRecycleView.setItemAnimator(new SlideInUpAnimator());
        mImageRecycleView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        prepareData();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main2, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    private void prepareData(){
        List<imageAdapter> data = new ArrayList<>();
        int[] images = {R.drawable.birthday_image_1,R.drawable.birthday_image_2,R.drawable.birthday_image_3,R.drawable.birthday_image_4,
              R.drawable.birthday_image_5,R.drawable.birthday_image_6,R.drawable.birthday_i    mage_7,R.drawable.birthday_image_8,
               R.drawable.birthday_image_9,R.drawable.birthday_image_10,R.drawable.birthday_    image_11,R.drawable.birthday_image_12};
        String[] description = {"ballons","a lot of cakes","ballons with cakes","presents","presents with hat","cup-cake",
                "retro","perspective","flying presents","empty card","giving a present","tasty cake"};
        for(int i = 0; i<images.length && i<description.length; i++){
            imageAdapter current = new imageAdapter();
            current.setTitle(description[i]);
            current.setImageId(images[i]);
            data.add(current);
        }
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

This the code for my second activity.It's not fully implemented but for sure the recyclerView doesn't work. Can anyone help me out with this. I believe that the problem is within my xmls .... but I cannot find anything.
PS. My code, when compiled shows no errors....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with the following code. Replace your prepareData() with mine

```
private void prepareData(){

    int[] images = {R.drawable.birthday_image_1,R.drawable.birthday_image_2,R.drawable.birthday_image_3,R.drawable.birthday_image_4,
          R.drawable.birthday_image_5,R.drawable.birthday_image_6,R.drawable.birthday_i    mage_7,R.drawable.birthday_image_8,
           R.drawable.birthday_image_9,R.drawable.birthday_image_10,R.drawable.birthday_    image_11,R.drawable.birthday_image_12};
    String[] description = {"ballons","a lot of cakes","ballons with cakes","presents","presents with hat","cup-cake",
            "retro","perspective","flying presents","empty card","giving a present","tasty cake"};
    for(int i = 0; i<images.length && i<description.length; i++){
        imageAdapter current = new imageAdapter();
        current.setTitle(description[i]);
        current.setImageId(images[i]);
        imageAdapterList.add(current);
    }
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: I doesn't work. Furthermore I just saw that I get a "I/Choreographer: Skipped 46 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread" message ... 
The only thing that I noticed, is that when I start the new activity, something appers on the upper right side (like a tiny grey rectangle) and it disappears after a second.

Comment: Then you might have problems with xml as well let me check it

Comment: Put a break point in onBindViewHolder and make sure that you are getting the call up to that.

Comment: The previous problem is that you are adding the data to another object and calling notify that will not work. You have to use the same instance of the object that you are past to the adapter in order call notify else it will not work .

Comment: I changed the code and modified some of the xml (by luck) and it works. Thanks.